Introduce sequence gaps in a ggplot lineplot
This might be a duplicate, but none of the questions I found seem to help my case.
I have a finaldf data frame that contains values at different time points, and specific time points are used as x-axis breaks (corresponding to a DNA sequence). I obtain it like this:
myseq <- "AGAATATTATACATTCATCT"
set.seed(123)
mydata <- data.frame(time=1:100, value=rnorm(100, mean=10, sd=2))
indices <- seq(5, 100, length.out=20)
seqsplit <- unlist(strsplit(myseq, ""))
ind_df <- data.frame(call=seqsplit, time=indices)
finaldf <- dplyr::left_join(mydata, ind_df, by="time")

It looks like this:
> finaldf
    time     value call
1      1  8.879049 <NA>
2      2  9.539645 <NA>
3      3 13.117417 <NA>
4      4 10.141017 <NA>
5      5 10.258575    A
6      6 13.430130 <NA>
7      7 10.921832 <NA>
8      8  7.469878 <NA>
9      9  8.626294 <NA>
10    10  9.108676    G
11    11 12.448164 <NA>
12    12 10.719628 <NA>
13    13 10.801543 <NA>
14    14 10.221365 <NA>
15    15  8.888318    A
...

And I plot it like this:
P <- ggplot2::ggplot(finaldf, ggplot2::aes(x=time, y=value)) +
  ggplot2::geom_line(linewidth=0.5) +
  ggplot2::scale_x_continuous(breaks=indices, labels=seqsplit) +
  ggplot2::theme_light()
grDevices::pdf(file="test.pdf", height=4, width=10)
print(P)
grDevices::dev.off()

Resulting in this plot:

Now I want to introduce different gaps in the sequence and obtain "gapped plots", identical to the one above but with gaps.
My starting point would be the original finaldf and different gapped sequences, identical to the original sequence but with gaps. For example:
gapseq1 <- "AGAA-TAT--TAT-ACATT---CATCT-"
gapseq2 <- "A-G-AATAT----TATACATTCA-TCT"

For these 2 gapped sequences, I want to recreate the following plots (ideally preserving the grid, but not needed):


How can I accomplish this in an easy way? Thanks!

Please provide your full test data using dput.  At the moment your gapped sequences are of a different length to your data frame.  The solution will most likely be to introduce an indicator variable to index the "not gap" parts of your sequences and then use this , in combination with group = 1 to define the appropriate aesthetics.  [Are gapseq1 and gapseq2 replacements for the call column in your test data?]

That is the whole point of the question... my starting point is the data for the ungapped sequence only, and then different versions of the sequence with gaps. The goal is to "complete" the data by adding the missing points for the gaps

Use gregexpr to find the indices of each "-" in your gap sequence and add_row to add rows to the data frame using these indices.
library(tibble)

(idx <- 5 * (gregexpr("-", gapseq1)[[1]]) - 2)

for(i in idx)
  finaldf <- finaldf |> add_row(value=rep(NA, 5), .before=i)

finaldf$time <- 1:nrow(finaldf) 
indices <- seq(5, nrow(finaldf), 5)
labels <- unlist(strsplit(gapseq1, ""))

ggplot2::ggplot(finaldf, ggplot2::aes(x=time, y=value)) +
  ggplot2::geom_line(linewidth=0.5) +
  ggplot2::scale_x_continuous(breaks=indices, labels=labels) +
  ggplot2::theme_light()





This is it! Thanks @Edward you saved my life twice today

Just remove the values when you don't want any point:
finaldf$value[rep(seqsplit == "-", each = 5)] <- NA



I get the following error when attempting finaldf$value[rep(seqsplit == "-", each = 5)] <- NA on the seqsplit of gapseq1: replacement has 140 rows, data has 100

yes that is because your gapseq1 are longer than your original myseq.
